# Problem to retrive realtime data from Firebase DB into google maps

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrive realtime location data from a Firebase DB and show multiple markers for each users in a Google map.

This is the structure of my Firebase DB:

[image: Firebase structure]

and this is the code of the Google Maps activity:

```
public class CyclistMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference UserRef;
    private String currentUserID;
    private static final String TAG = CyclistMapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private HashMap<String, Marker> mMarkers = new HashMap<>();

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cyclist_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(16);
        subscribeToUpdates();
    }

    private void subscribeToUpdates() {
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        final String path = "/latlong";
        UserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users"+currentUserID+path);

        DatabaseReference ref = UserRef;
        ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                setMarker(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                setMarker(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
    }

    private void setMarker(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
        HashMap<String, Object> value = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("/latlong").getValue();
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(value.get("latitude").toString());
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(value.get("longitude").toString());
        LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lng);

        if (!mMarkers.containsKey(key)) {
            mMarkers.put(key, mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(key).position(location)));
        } else {
            mMarkers.get(key).setPosition(location);
        }
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        for (Marker marker : mMarkers.values()) {
            builder.include(marker.getPosition());
        }
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 300));
    }
}
```

When I try to run my app, the locations of all users are updated every 5 seconds in the Firebase database, but the makers are not shown on the Google map.

I see this error in my logcat:

```
"W/Bundle: Key getPairValue() expected String but value was a java.lang.Float.  The default value <null> was returned."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues in your code. You reference does not contain `/` between `"Users"+currentUser`, should be `"Users/"+currentUser`. And that error occurs because you are trying to get that value as a String while it is a float. To get the `latitude` and `longitude` in a correct and more simpler way, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference latlongRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid).child("latlong");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        double latitude = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
        double longitude = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
        Log.d(TAG, latitude + ", " + longitude);
        setMarker(latitude, longitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
latlongRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in the logcat will be:

```
53,45, 9.14
```

Once you have both `latitude` and `longitude`, you can call a method to add the markers to the map.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works fine! Now I'll try to show the markers  from all users logged in my app in real time. Have you any suggestions?

Comment: Good to hear that it worked :) Trying to show the markers from all logged in users, should basically be considered another question that cannot be answered in a comment. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other Firebase developers can help you.